# Add Chapter Title to Header - without "Chapter 1"

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm looking for the way (assuming there is one) of putting the current page's chapter title in the header of the page. Basically, what I want is:

[image]

where only the chapter's title ("First Chapter" in this case) shows up.

However, what I get is:

[image]

or some variant, but always with "Chapter 1" or just "Chapter" in there.

My code is:

```
 % AUTHOR: Enter the title, all letters in upper case
\def \booktitle{Trial Title}
\def \currentrevision{A}
\def \documentnumber{ME-MAN-001}

\title{\booktitle}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}

% \fancyhead[LE,RO]{FIRST CHAPTER}

\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\documentnumber~Rev.~\currentrevision}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
```

Yes, I am using fancyhdr and I've reviewed the documentation and tried the variants, but nothing seems to work. I've also tried too many things to detail here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to adjust `\chaptermark` to avoid inserting the `\@chapapp \thechapter.` prefix. It's truly as simple as adding

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}
```

to your preamble. Here's a complete, minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}

\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\documentnumber~Rev.~\currentrevision}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}

\def \currentrevision{A}
\def \documentnumber{ME-MAN-001}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

---

This is also fairly straight-forward using [`titleps`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titleps):

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titleps,lipsum}
\newpagestyle{main}{
  \setheadrule{.4pt}% Header rule
  %\setfootrule{.4pt}% Footer rule
  \sethead[\documentnumber~Rev.~\currentrevision]% odd-left
          []% odd-center
          [\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}]% odd-right
          {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}}% even-left
          {}% even-center
          {\documentnumber~Rev.~\currentrevision}% even-right
  \setfoot[]% odd-left
          []% odd-center
          [\thepage]% odd-right
          {\thepage}% even-left
          {}% even-center
          {}% even-right
}
\pagestyle{main}

\def \currentrevision{A}
\def \documentnumber{ME-MAN-001}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

If you're interested in switching from [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) to `titleps`, see [`titleps` for `fancyhdr` users](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/titleps_fancyhdr.html).

Comment: I love `titlesec` and friends, but *boy* do they make the simple things seem complicated.

Comment: Ah!! The key was that the \renewcommand must come after the \pagestyle declaration. Seems obvious now, but not then. Anyway, I really appreciate the responses. Thanks.

Comment: @Dave: You can place it before the `\pagestyle` as well. Try it out. If this answered your question, consider [accepting it as such](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ).

Comment: @Werner: That's why I pointed it out...it doesn't work if you (well, I) put it before \pagestyle. Now I want to do the same with Section (i.e. get rid of the numbering.)Thanks