# I need the fancy for my page header like this picture

Tags: header-footer

I need the special code header for:

[image]

Comment: Welcome, isn't that the default header? -> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers

Comment: many thanks, but i need the number of chapter in left side and the name only of chapter in right side in the page. I'v already use the link that you are mention but i can't founded this style.

Comment: We have absolutely no clue what's going on, please have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/How_to_get_help

Comment: welcome to tex.se!  please provide us small complete document with some short dummy text beginning with `\documentclass{...}` followed by preamble, `\begin{document}`,  some short dummy text as document body and with `\end{document}` on the end.

Comment: You might also look at the fancyhdr package, \chaptername, \thechapter and \chaptermark.  AFAIK, there is no built-in macro to convert numbers to text (one, two, three,...) but a limited set can be implmented sing \ifcase (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392593/latex-how-to-get-question-number-in-exam-package/392635?s=4|7.0846#392635).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of a MWE, it's hard to know if this solution is right for you. But, here is a proposal using the `report` document class. (Don't know which document class you are actually using). It uses:

- `fancyhdr`
- `fmtcount` to get the chapter number written out as a word (using `\numberstringnum{\thechapter}`. See [Convert any number to corresponding word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28326/convert-any-number-to-corresponding-word/).
- `\leftmark` gives the chapter name, but we need add `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}` to remove the word chapter, see [Add Chapter Title to Header - without “Chapter 1”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222048/add-chapter-title-to-header-without-chapter-1).

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext} % For dummy text
\usepackage{fmtcount}  % Display the value of a counter
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  % For fancy headers

\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Chapter \numberstringnum{\thechapter}}
\rhead{\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\chapter{Test}

\chapter{Symmetrical components}
\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much for solved my problem you're the best.