# I need help in getting chapter title (without number) to display in header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I want my two-sided pages to have different headers: on the left (even) side, the title of the book, and on the right (odd) side, the chapter title, without number. (This is pretty normal for non-technical books.)

I adapted my code from Werner's answer to Dave's 2015 question "[Add Chapter Title to Header - without “Chapter 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222048/add-chapter-title-to-header-without-chapter-1)” without success. The left (even) header is fine, but all I get is a separation line on the top of the right (odd) pages with no chapter title.

See minimum (non-)working example below. Is the problem in line 6? Do I need to rearrange some lines? I've searched sundry places including the fancyhdr documentation without success. Thanks in advance,
Artmancc

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[CE]{T~I~T~L~E~~~~O~F~~~~T~H~I~S~~~~B~O~O~K} 
\fancyhead[CO]{\leftmark}  %%% Is this the problem?
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}


\begin{document}

\chapter*{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-9]
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}  %% no header on blank left page
\chapter*{Last Chapter}
\lipsum[10-18]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The starred version `\chapter*` does not execute `\chaptermark`. So you have to add this command for each starred chapter:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{emptypage}% page style empty on blank pages

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[CE]{T~I~T~L~E~~~~O~F~~~~T~H~I~S~~~~B~O~O~K} 
\fancyhead[CO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{First Chapter}\chaptermark{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-9]
\chapter*{Last Chapter}\chaptermark{Last Chapter}
\lipsum[10-18]

\end{document}
```

The result for this example is the same as above.

[image]

But if there are no numbered chapters, sections etc in the document, it would be better to change counter `secnumpdepth` and use the unstarred version `\chapter`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{emptypage}% page style empty on blank pages

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[CE]{T~I~T~L~E~~~~O~F~~~~T~H~I~S~~~~B~O~O~K} 
\fancyhead[CO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}% only parts will be numbered

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-9]
\chapter{Last Chapter}
\lipsum[10-18]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy with `titleps` which comes with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{myfancy}{%
\sethead[][T~I~T~L~E~~~~O~F~~~~T~H~I~S~~~~B~O~O~K][]{}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitle}}{}
\setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myfancy}

\chapter*{First Chapter}
\chaptermark{First Chapter}
\lipsum[1-9]
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage} %% no header on blank left page
\chapter*{Last Chapter}
\chaptermark{Last Chapter}
\lipsum[10-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this out. But I still want to know — if only as a learning exercise — why my code failed.

Comment: For your try, don't load both fancyhdr and titleps – they're incompatible.